# Cordova App with Venmo integrated site rendered in Webview

Tags: cordova, webview, braintree, venmo

I have a cordova app with webview that renders a website.

The website is integrated with Venmo payment. When I open the Cordova App, site is rendered, I proceed with the payment, click on Venmo button that opens the Venmo app in the iOS Mobile and after authorisation, it is getting redirected to Safari browser instead of Cordova App.

Please suggest some fix so that It should be redirected to Cordova App instead of Safari browser.

Comment: adding the code that you have tried will be helpful

Comment: @con It is just a inAppBrowser opening the site thats all